# mysql - trigger, multiple statements for same event & time

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'd like to make 2 fields (firstname & lastname) of the same table "clients" uppercase upon insert.

```
mysql> show triggers LIKE 'clients'\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Trigger: ucase_insert
               Event: INSERT
               Table: tlc
           Statement: SET NEW.firstname = upper(NEW.firstname)
              Timing: BEFORE
             Created: 2017-02-04 11:53:45.87
            sql_mode: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
             Definer: root@%
character_set_client: utf8mb4
collation_connection: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  Database Collation: utf8_general_ci
```

I use phpmyadmin as interface. It seems that I can't add an additional second statement like ...

```
           Statement: SET NEW.lastname = upper(NEW.lastname)
```

... which is supposed to trigger at the same event and time as the first one.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. With `BEGIN` / `END`, I can include multiple statements. Seems trivial, but took me quite a while to find out ...

```
mysql> show triggers LIKE 'clients'\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Trigger: ucase_insert
               Event: INSERT
               Table: tlc
           Statement: BEGIN
SET NEW.firstname = upper(NEW.firstname);
SET NEW.lastname = upper(NEW.lastname);
END
           Timing: BEFORE
             Created: 2017-02-04 11:53:45.87
            sql_mode: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
             Definer: root@%
character_set_client: utf8mb4
collation_connection: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  Database Collation: utf8_general_ci
```